# Noun for someone with a childlike heart (positive)

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What noun could be used to describe someone ingenuous, innocent, with a child like heart?

Comment: A *naif*. An *innocent*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The French word [ingénue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingenue_(stock_character)) has acquired some currency in English.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with **[artless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artless)**:

> free from guile or craft :  sincerely simple

In case you're open to adjectives

Comment: -1 that is an adjective, not a noun!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can say that he/she is a ***candid*** person or talk about his/her ***candidness***

Answer (score 0):

It's often used sarcastically, but I would say a [dear](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dear), "a  person who is good, kind, or generous" (sense 10).